# Add the title attribute to links

Tags: links, html, title, customization

I want to add a title attribute to my link like this:

```
<a href="#" title="here is the title">LINK</a>
```

I know how to do this in html but I can't expect this from my users.

I can't find anywhere in WordPress how to do this and there isn't a `theme_support` function for this.

I can't be the first to encounter this problem (I hope).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you are not the only one: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32095

It looks like this was removed in a recent update (4.2) and I can see why they did it. User interface can be confusing at times.

You can read more about the removal here: http://wptavern.com/how-to-restore-the-link-title-attribute-removed-in-wordpress-4-2

There is a WordPress plugin, however, that seems to add it back for you. I have not tested, but it should work:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/restore-link-title-field/